# Wordpress [wpquery] orderby

Tags: wordpress, сортировка, wordpress-плагины

Добрый день, на WP есть установленный плагин [Post Views Counter](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/).
Для него есть шорткод: `[post-views]`

Как его вставить в wpquery так, чтобы он работал?

```
$populargb = new WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name=photo,video&orderby=[post-views]');
```

Также есть таблица `wp_post_views` со строкой `count`, в которой находится количество просмотров.

Или предложите аналогичный вариант для сортировке по количеству просмотров.
Также в таблице `wp_postmeta` есть данные по `view`:

```
meta_key: post_views_count
meta_value: числовое значение(0,1,2,3,4,5......)
```

Пробовал сделать такое но не сортирует по к-ву просмотров:

```
                <?php $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'category_name' => 'photo,video',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'post_views_count',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                    ),
                ),
            );
            $populargb = new WP_Query($args);
            while ($populargb->have_posts()) : $populargb->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Авторы плагина пишут](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-sort-by-post-views-using-meta-value/#post-7399682), что не используют мета поля для записей, а добавили новый параметр для сортировки по количеству просмотров.

> PVC does not store views in postmeta so your setting will not work,
>   but it extends WP_query with a new orderby parameter

Судя по коду плагина, это `post_views`. Попробуйте:

```
$populargb = new WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name=photo,video&orderby=post_views');
```